# Why does my Mac Pro crash (or log out) almost everyday. Can anybody help?

Tags: mac, crash, kernel-panic, macos

i have a Mac Pro Mid 2010 (10.13.6 (17G5019)/2 x 3,46 GHz 6-Core Intel Xeon/128 GB 1333 MHz DDR3/NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti 6143 MB) and experience terribly annoying crashes (mostly suddenly logging out but also kernel panics) for a year or so. I work mostly in After Effects. I don't know if the kernel panics and Logouts refer to each other, but i guess so. So i hereby post a recent Kernel Panic crash report. Any help is so much appreciated! Thanks in advance!:

```
Mon Mar 11 10:51:56 2019

*** Panic Report *** panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8006a897b4): "thread_invoke: preemption_level 1, possible cause: blocking while holding a spinlock, or within interrupt context"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4570.71.22/osfmk/kern/sched_prim.c:2231 Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address 0xffffffce46a63620 : 0xffffff8006a6e1c6  0xffffffce46a63670 : 0xffffff8006b96a74  0xffffffce46a636b0 : 0xffffff8006b88d44  0xffffffce46a63720 : 0xffffff8006a201e0  0xffffffce46a63740 : 0xffffff8006a6dc3c  0xffffffce46a63870 : 0xffffff8006a6d9fc  0xffffffce46a638d0 : 0xffffff8006a897b4  0xffffffce46a63950 : 0xffffff8006a8863f  0xffffffce46a639a0 : 0xffffff8006b82346  0xffffffce46a63a00 : 0xffffff8006a1eb0d  0xffffffce46a63a20 : 0xffffff8006af3831  0xffffffce46a63b00 : 0xffffff8006aba563  0xffffffce46a63c30 : 0xffffff8006a4fc76  0xffffffce46a63c60 : 0xffffff8006a50863  0xffffffce46a63cb0 : 0xffffff8006a73e52  0xffffffce46a63cf0 : 0xffffff7f873888bd  0xffffffce46a63d30 : 0xffffff7f873dfee9  0xffffffce46a63d50 : 0xffffff7f8749845e  0xffffffce46a63da0 : 0xffffff7f874dd9fc  0xffffffce46a63dc0 : 0xffffff7f87b4bfc8  0xffffffce46a63e10 : 0xffffff7f873e70dc  0xffffffce46a63ed0 : 0xffffff800709a075  0xffffffce46a63f30 : 0xffffff80070987e2  0xffffffce46a63f70 : 0xffffff8007097e0c  0xffffffce46a63fa0 : 0xffffff8006a1f557 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.nvidia.web.NVDAResmanWeb(10.3.3)[17CB9A59-D16E-3610-86F5-E1ADBABEE7F8]@0xffffff7f87381000->0xffffff7f879f9fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D91E9813-9717-31B8-BFE5-2F3A00F375F3]@0xffffff7f87294000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(519.21)[8E0EE518-0D53-38C0-B308-2C6CD9EC5B7B]@0xffffff7f87365000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.21)[E5B53C5D-BF6E-3D72-9091-A80DFE5426C9]@0xffffff7f8730f000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.20.14)[D3CF5F89-2DA6-3F73-995D-F5DDE191E192]@0xffffff7f87375000
         com.nvidia.web.NVDAGM100HalWeb(10.3.3)[7562E226-6E34-3649-8E77-FF522EBD60C8]@0xffffff7f87a10000->0xffffff7f87bb3fff
            dependency: com.nvidia.web.NVDAResmanWeb(10.3.3)[17CB9A59-D16E-3610-86F5-E1ADBABEE7F8]@0xffffff7f87381000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D91E9813-9717-31B8-BFE5-2F3A00F375F3]@0xffffff7f87294000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version: 17G5019

Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Dec 20 21:47:19 PST 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.22~1/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID: 4A5298BF-709E-37DF-B7F0-4298065CC266 Kernel slide:     0x0000000006800000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff8006a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8006900000 System model name: MacPro5,1 (Mac-F221BEC8) _
```

**Edit:** Thanks so far already! You gave me several very useful hints! 
So, i indeed have a lot of stuff inside apart from the 980ti: 1x Geforce GT 120, 1x DVD-RW, 1x m2 SSD (via PCI 512GB), 1x SSD(512GB), 3xHDD(3TB/2TB/1TB), 1x USB 3.0 Card.
Now it makes a lot of sense to me, that this is supposed to be power related in the first place. 
But something maybe even more evident:
I found this contentful video on GPU Setup (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AIPw2jCr9o) and just the kind of adapter that is explicitly to be avoided for all the times is the one i used to connect my card, which is a mini 6-Pin to 8 adapter (gives a good chance to burn out the power port on the main board). So first, this is the one to remove and to replace with one of the solutions shown in the video and then see what happens. The second thing would be to withdraw some drives or the GT 120 i guess.

Comment: Is that a 4,1 upgraded to 5,1? There never was a 3.46GHz at new, only with upgrade. Can you tell us, specifically, which NVidia drivers you're using - use this list to be certain - http://www.macvidcards.com/drivers.html [Similar, unresolved issue - https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/1081181/problem-kernel-panics-with-nvidia-web-drivers-mac-osx/ ]

Comment: Hi, thanks. I upgraded the CPU indeed. But i'm pretty sure it was always a 5,1. I have the latest NVIDIA Driver 10.13.6  (17G5019) 387.10.10.10.40.122 and CUDA Driver Version: 410.130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would be a bit wary about running a 980 Ti with the stock power supply in a 2010 Mac Pro, power draw might be an issue. It's a 250W card, and the 2010 Mac Pro has a 980W stock PSU. If there's a lot of extra draw on the PSU that might cause it to trip out, which could be a factor if you've upgraded the hardware.

Secondly, do you have CUDA installed? Try uninstalling CUDA. I encountered a similar situation last year, but I don't recall the exact panic text. If uninstalling doesn't help, CUDA can be easily reinstalled afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! I have CUDA Driver Version: 410.130 . I will check how this behaves after uninstalling Cuda, and keep You up-to-date... though in my understanding i'll lose the main benefits of this card without Cuda...

Comment: I can't comment on [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/353584/why-does-my-mac-pro-crash-or-log-out-almost-everyday-can-anybody-help/353599#comment466101_353584) yet, but there's a newer CUDA for 17G5019 -- as of now, it's [418.105](https://www.nvidia.com/object/macosx-cuda-418.105-driver.html). If uninstalling CUDA does make a difference, next thing to try would be updating to that version (or later, if a newer one appears in the meantime). Edit: typo.

Comment: I keep coming back to power consumption…a 980W PSU, assuming 80% efficiency, should give you around 780W of usable juice. Subtract 250W for the GPU, and subtract a further 260W for the processors -- that leaves around 260W left. What other items need power inside the case? I'm assuming hard drives -- how many, and what type?

Comment: Also, are you running the 980Ti power from the motherboard or from a PSU connector? I have a vague memory that some older Mac Pros have 12V out on the motherboard for a GPU, but pulling 250W from a motherboard is too much. Perhaps an adaptor to split a 12V connection from the optical drive to a 6- or 8-pin GPU input might be worth a try.

Comment: Hi, i removed the diabolic mini 6-Pin to 8 adapter from the motherboard, withdrew the power from the optical drive and sent it via a 2x6-Pin to 8-Pin adapter to the GPUs 8-Pin. Kept the the GPUs 6-Pin power from the motherboard. No crashes yet and it feels great. So no PSU,GPU, CUDA or Driver issues here! Thank You Pete, You saved my Mac!

Comment: Fantastic news. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a common problem with your setup. [Nvidia Support](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/930758/geforce-drivers/-problem-spontaneous-kernel-panics-with-nvidia-web-driver-on-mac/1/)
Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to comment on @Pete Cooper, but he pretty much nailed it.  Solutions:

- New PSU
- New GFX card (preferably one that draws less power)
- Uninstall CUDA
- Make sure drivers are all up-to-date [MacVidCards](http://www.macvidcards.com/drivers.html)